# Add MapActivity to FragmentLayout

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio, android-mapview

I have to create an Android App for the university. It will store data in a database and on button click I will get some data and want to display the data on a map.

This is the map Layout:

[image]

The grey part is the MapView. Now my question:

Can I do this in Android Studio or do I have to use a FragmentLayout. Can`t find any similar questions, unfortunately. I want to display the map in this Relative Layout.

Thanks in advance

Edit:

Here is the activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSend"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:text="Senden" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textEdit"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="104dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="Hier Text eingeben"
        tools:text="Hier Text eingeben" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textInfo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonReceive"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textEdit"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:text="Empfangen" />

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="336dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can u share your xml code ?

Comment: added the activity xml code @pravin

Comment: add map like : **`<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>`** @Shpeeon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSend"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:text="Senden" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textEdit"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="104dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="Hier Text eingeben"
        tools:text="Hier Text eingeben" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textInfo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonReceive"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textEdit"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:text="Empfangen" />


    <fragment android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="336dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" 
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```